# Including my own jar in a maven project. What groupId should I provide?

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to using maven and am trying to include my own jar files in a maven project. This is described in the following link - https://maven.apache.org/general.html. In order to understand what the different fields meant in -

```
mvn install:install-file
-Dfile=<path-to-file>
-DgroupId=<group-id>
-DartifactId=<artifact-id>
-Dversion=<version>
-Dpackaging=<packaging>
-DgeneratePom=true
```

I took a look at this other link - http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html

Most of the fields are clear to me except the groupId. It says I have to own a domain? Can't I just include my jar in the project without owning a domain?

Here is the pom generated after I use the install command -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sorting</groupId>
<artifactId>Algorithms2</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<description>POM was created from install:install-file</description>
 </project>
```

Comment: make it whatever you want as long as it is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create java files, you should have a package name also. It is probably a good idea to use some prefix substring of that package name as a guideline for the groupId.

Comment: Thanks jordan. That worked. However, I now can't include a class from that jar in the java files of the src folder of my maven project. When I do that and say mvn package, I get a build error - package sorting (I tried to import sorting.quickfind) doesn't exist.

Comment: I dont exactly understand what youre trying to do, sorry. What is the full error message? Do you have 2 maven projects you have created now with one that should depend on the other? Have you configured that dependency in maven?

Comment: Maybe also include the pom file that was created.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear and thanks for the patience. There is one maven project which compiles and runs fine and another eclipse project for which I created the a jar. I now want to use my own jar file in the maven project. For that, I used the mvn:install command, which worked. I now want to use a method from one of the classes in my jar file in the maven project and so, am trying to import the method into one of the java files in the src directory of the maven project. This is where I'm getting the error that it can't find my class.

Comment: Did you run "mvn install" in the folder where the pom file for "Algorithms2" artifact is? Or did you run it to install your eclipse project's jar into the maven repository?

Comment: If your non-maven project depends on the maven project, then the non-maven project needs to add the jar file created from the maven project to its classpath.  If your maven project depends on the non-maven project, then the maven project needs to add a dependency (see maven documentation) to that non-maven project (i.e. point to its jar on the filesystem). If you are using maven, it is often best to convert all projects to be maven projects, instead of mixing maven and non-maven projects. It can certainly be done with mixing, but it is most streamlined when it is all maven or all not maven.

Comment: Thanks for your help, jordan. Adding the dependency to my main pom file solved the problem.